# KVC strange behavior

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

Why this code works fine:

```
NSArray* arr = @[[CALayer layer], [CALayer layer]];
NSString *sumKeyPath = @"@sum.bounds.size.width";
CGFloat totalSize = [[arr valueForKeyPath:sumKeyPath] floatValue];
```

But this code give error:

```
NSArray* arr = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"]];
NSString *sumKeyPath = @"@sum.size.width";
CGFloat totalSize = [[arr valueForKeyPath:sumKeyPath] floatValue];
```

**Error**:
*[NSConcreteValue valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key width.*

```
NSArray* arr = @[[UIView new], [UIView new]];
NSString *sumKeyPath = @"@sum.bounds.size.width";
CGFloat totalSize = [[arr valueForKeyPath:sumKeyPath] floatValue];
```

give the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CALayer` has a special implementation for `valueForKeyPath:`. For example, the following works:

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
id x0 = [layer valueForKeyPath:@"bounds"];
// --> NSValue object containing a NSRect
id y0 = [layer valueForKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
// --> NSValue object containing a NSSize
id z0 = [layer valueForKeyPath:@"bounds.size.width"];
// --> NSNumber object containing a float
```

But the following does not work:

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
id x = [layer valueForKey:@"bounds"];
// --> NSValue object containing a NSRect
id y = [x valueForKey:@"size"];
// --> Exception: '[<NSConcreteValue 0x71189e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key size.'
```

So generally, `NSValue` objects containing a `NSRect` or `NSSize` are *not* key-value compliant. It works only with `CALayer` because the `valueForKeyPath:` implementation handles the entire key path, instead of evaluating the first key and passing down the remaining key path.

`UIImage` does not have a special implementation for `valueForKeyPath:`. Therefore

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"];
id x1 = [img1 valueForKey:@"size"];
// --> NSValue containing a NSSize
```

works, but

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"];
id x1 = [img1 valueForKeyPath:@"size.width"];
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error tells you exactly what that problem is! "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key width."

Comment: What difference? bounds- not NSObject, size- not NSObject. Why first code works fine? Size in first case have same type and in the second case.

Comment: See @martin's answer. `CALayer` does clever stuff in `valueForKeyPath:` (sometimes).