# Getting the min/max coordinates of NSValue transformed CGPoints in an NSArray using KVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, kvc

I recently read some documentation and some blog entries about `Key-Value Coding` and found it extremely useful. I want to utilize it for my case, but I haven't been successful so far.

In my case, I have an `NSMutableArray` containing `CGPoint`'s transformed to `NSValue`'s. I will be adding many points to this data array and I want to get the minimum/maximum x and y values. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(20.0f, 10.0f)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.0f, -15.0f)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-5.0f, 20.0f)]];
[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15.0f, 30.0f)]];

// min X:  -5.0,  max X: 20.0
// min Y: -15.0,  max Y: 30.0
```

I have two approaches so far. The first one is to store these four values in class instance variables and when a new object is added, compare it with those variables and update them if necessary. The second one involves a for-loop to to find the extremum values, however this approach would be inefficient.

If possible, I would like to use KVC to do this task and I believe that it would be a more general solution than those I have. In the future, I might also need to remove some of the objects from the array and that would make my first approach inapplicable and all I am left with would be the for-loop.

I tried to use some key paths, i.e. `@"@max.x"`, `@"@max.position.x"` but all I got is an `NSUnknownKeyException`.

Comment: Where are these key paths coming from?  Anyway, if you keep your array sorted then you will have a much better time (and you won't need a for loop either).  You can insert via divide and conquer (start in the middle, go halfway either way depending on if the value is higher or lower, should only take a maximum of about 7 tries per 100 values).

Comment: @borrrden, I cannot sort the array because these data are for plotting purposes. I got the keyPaths from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html): `CGPoint Key Paths
If the value of a given property is a CGPoint data type, you can append one of the field names in Table C-3 to the property to get or set that value. For example, to change the x component of a layer’s position property, you could write to the key path position.x.`

Comment: I meant the "max" thing.  What is that?

Comment: @tolgamorf: It works if you access the key path of a of `CALayer`, but not with a general `NSValue`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/15657943/1187415.

Comment: @borrrden `max` can be used for example to get the maximum value of an array of NSNumbers. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3080688/1576979).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I also saw it in the documentation but I thought maybe I could use a similar keyPath for CGPoints as well. But, apparently not.

Comment: @borrrden also this [blog entry](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) has nice explanations for simple collection operators that can be used in key paths.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew about this!

Comment: Indeed, it makes some operations really simple. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* make it work if you use a category to tell `NSValue` how to access the `x` and `y` value of a `CGPoint`:

```
@interface NSValue (MyKeyCategory)
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key;
@end

@implementation NSValue (MyKeyCategory)
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if (strcmp([self objCType], @encode(CGPoint)) == 0) {
        CGPoint p = [self CGPointValue];
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"x"]) {
            return @(p.x);
        } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"y"]) {
            return @(p.y);
        }
    }
    return [super valueForKey:key];
}
@end
```

Then

```
CGFloat maxx = [[yourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.x"] floatValue];
```

actually works. But note that a simple loop will be much faster, in particular if you have to compute all 4 values `@max.x`, `@max.y`, `@min.x`, `@min.y`.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with your current approach. A `CGPoint` is not an obj-c object, so you can't explore its values by KVC. `NSValue` sees `CGPoint` only as a binary data and has no understaning about the inner structure of the data. The names `x` and `y` for `CGPoint` fields are not even accessible after compilation.

(The only exception when `CGPoint` values can be accessed by KVC are `CAAnimation` and `CALayer` which override the key-value search).

Possibly the best solution is to implement it by yourself, note that you can do some clever caching - test current max/min when adding points and clear min/max when current min/max is removed.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a custom keyPath or an implementation based on my approach?

Comment: @tolgamorf I am suggesting to leave KVC altogether and wrap the array and min/max search into a special class.