# Type 'CGPoint' has no member 'x' when using #keyPath in CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am trying to use the #keyPath syntax in order to get a CALayer property to animate it like this:

```
let myAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position.x))
```

and I get the following error:

> Type 'CGPoint' has no member 'x'

What am I missing?

Comment: USe `let myAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "position.x")` let me know if works as should

Comment: `kvo`  doesn't apply for `struct`s. Only classes can have this functionality. Note `struct` is immutable so kvo is pointless.

Comment: @MarekR CALayer is a class, not a struct
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer

Comment: @TheoK but `CGPoint` is a struct so `x` can't be observed. Key path is simply to long. Note error message is about `CGPoint` not `CALayer`.

Comment: @MarekR Ok. My bad, I thought that you were referring to CALayer. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with structs and #keyPath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#keyPath` directive expects an Objective-C property sequence as
argument. `CALayer` inherits from `NSObject`, but its `position`
property is `struct CGPoint`, which is not a class at all, and cannot
used with Key-Value coding.

*However,* `CALayer` has a special implementation of `value(forKeyPath:)`
which handles the entire key path, instead of evaluating the first key and passing down the remaining key path, compare  [KVC strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657156/kvc-strange-behavior).

So Key-Value Coding *can* be used with "position.x", but the 
compiler does not know about this special treatment.
As an example, this all compiles and runs:

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.position = CGPoint(x: 4, y: 5)

print(layer.value(forKeyPath: "position"))   // Optional(NSPoint: {4, 5}
print(layer.value(forKeyPath: "position.x")) // Optional(4)

print(layer.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))) // Optional(NSPoint: {4, 5})
```

but this does not compile:

```
print(layer.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position.x)))
// error: Type 'CGPoint' has no member 'x'
```

That is the reason why

```
let myAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position.x))
```

does not compile, but this does ([as Reinier Melian suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964282/type-cgpoint-has-no-member-x-when-using-keypath-in-cabasicanimation#comment84934670_48964282)):

```
let myAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
```

Answer (score 1):

`position` is a property in object of type `CALayer` and you want to access it from base class , second keyPath takes a property to animate in the layer and `CALayer.position.x` is not a property inside CALayer object that you want to animate , so it must be `position.x` that you can't write directly without string "" as you will have error saying can't find position in the class you want to declare it in , so proper way would be like this

```
  let myLayer = CALayer.init()
  myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
  let anim =  CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "position.x")
  anim.fromValue = 20
  anim.toValue = 100
  anim.duration = 1
  myLayer.add(myAnimation, forKey: "position.x")
  self.view.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

Comment: I know this alternative. The question is why the #keyPath syntax in this instance is returning this error.

Comment: can you edit your original answer, so that it reflects the actual question?